# rbind a list of data.frames while keeping NULL elements in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to `rbind` a `list` of `data.frame` and transform `NULL` elements into NA using R. Consider the following example,

```
l <- list(data.frame(C1 = 1, C2 = 2),
          NULL,
          data.frame(C1 = 3))

# bind_rows results
dplyr::bind_rows(l)

#   C1 C2
# 1  1  2
# 2  3 NA

# Desired output
data.frame(C1 = c(1, NA, 3), C2 = c(2, NA, NA))

#   C1 C2
# 1  1  2
# 2 NA NA
# 3  3 NA
```

Comment: having a NULL and making it a NA is not the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with transforming the NULL elements:

```
l <- lapply(l, function(x) if(is.null(x)) data.frame(C1 = NA) else x)

dplyr::bind_rows(l)
#  C1 C2
#1  1  2
#2 NA NA
#3  3 NA
```

Comment: Feel like pretty inefficient method. I would go with `l[!lengths(l)] <- list(data.frame(C1 = NA))`

Comment: I doubt that the list has enough elements that such performance considerations are important. This should probably be solved upstream anyway. Why are there `NULL` elements to begin with?

Comment: @Roland. It's a list of responses to http queries, some of which are ``NULL`` because the query gives no results. Thanks for the answer, it works well!